# My dishwasher suddenly stopped working, and I don’t know much about electricity. Any tips

Tags: electrical, dishwasher

[image: picture of where the dishwaher, plug, and garbage disposal hook up.]

Hello!
Recently our dishwasher stopped working in our apartment. The plug above it and the garbage disposal also stopped working, leading me to believe it’s a power issue. I followed the wires and they all three connect up into the same spot (attached picture). I’ve already called the landlord, but it’s marked as a low priority. Is there anything that I could possibly do to fix it by myself? I don’t know a lot about electricity, but I’m willing to try.

Anything look off to you about the picture, or just some general steps I can try to see if that will work?

Comment: That is an unsafe condition with an open box and wires not properly strain relieved. However it is probably not the source of your problem.  You should have a fuse or circuit breaker box in your apartment. That is where you should look as the most probable event is that either a fuse blew or a circuit breaker tripped.

Comment: Have you checked the breaker panel, if the panel is properly identified find the correct breaker and turn it all the way to off then back on it may be a simple trip because of overload all the devices on at the same time. The box should have a cover did you remove it for this picture?

Comment: @EdBeal Nope, I didn't remove the box, it was like that when we moved in!

I checked the breaker panel and turned each one off individually (they were not marked), but no dice. Should I have tried the main switch? or will that cause a power outage?

Comment: Since this is the only thing out the main should be fine. I am guessing the outlet feeds these it is possible that there is a bad connection in the outlet box,  or the outlet prior if dasiy chained. This is where the breaker should be turned off and pull the outlet to look for a bad connection or burnt wire since the ones in the open box look ok from the photo.

Comment: My comment is more practical than electrical. Like you said it's the landlords responsibility, let him fix it. If you make an attempt to repair it the liability falls on you for any damage to his property. Reset the breaker and check for voltage but that would be about all I would do. Maybe you can call, him bring his attention to this string about the unsafe condition and push him a little to move you up the priority ladder.

Comment: @RetiredMasterElectrician That's probably what i'll end up doing. It looks like the problem stretches far past just wiggling a wire or flipping the breaker on and off (the only things I know how to do anyways!)

Comment: @EdBeal thank you for helping me out! At least I was able to figure out that it wasn't something I am able to fix :)